# Facebook application: insights not updated

Tags: facebook, statistics

For publishing your facebook app offcially, you need 10 monthly users or 5 total users (check out the paradox :s), but the thing is, while quite a lot of people have visited my app, and about 30 liked it, my insight statistics aren't updated, so I can't publish the app --'

Does anyone know how long it takes before they update the statistics?

Comment: I'm sure you have more than 5 friends that you could get to install your app. Paradox solved.

Comment: You may want to try web apps stack exchange for this question.

Comment: @Thorn007 good use.